# IS jquery/javascript validation correct for submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

I have one issue. Like when ever we are putting any validation or using some selectors within a form. Now Before submission of Form suppose i opened firebug or similar tool, and I changed the **ID or class** to something else. and submitted the form is it correct ?

For Example: Suppose i have a Date input field with class **pdate** to select past date and class **fdate** for future date. Now suppose added a jQuery validation with those classes for respective selection. But using firebug if i am changing **pdate** to **fdate** and submitting the form, Now i just want to be sure how data is correct here?

What should be a good approach for such case???

Comment: Secure against **what**?

Comment: First, what is meant by "secure".  Secondly, client-side validation is nice looking but can be easily bypassed.  Always use server-side validation to protect your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Client-side logic cannot be secure.

You always need to validate everything on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't trust client-side to validate your data. Client-side validation is good to help user fill the from correctly but the real validation should be done on the server-side.